# Wildcard Use in Bind Records to Match some Subdomains

Tags: bind, dns-zone, dns-record

I have a main domain ( aa.example.com) with hunderds of subdomains ( bb.aa.example.com). I made a wildcard record to forward all subdomains (bb.) to a list of addresses in  round-robin fashion. The problem I am fscing is the wildcard is forwarding anything towards the the IP ( example , "cc.bb." which is not a vaild subdomain). How can I limit that so it will only forwards ( bb.aa.example.com) and drops any invalid subdomains ( cc.bb.aa.example.com ).

Note: aa, bb, and cc being any arbitary value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wildcard matches anything below.

So `*.example.com` will match for both `a.example.com` but also `a.b.example.com` or `a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l.m.n.o.p.q.r.s.t.u.v.w.x.y.example.com`, due to the way the resolution algorithm works.

If you don't want this, you need to change the architecture of your DNS tree.

If you have a fixed list of subdomains below `example.com` then define them explicitly, and remove the wildcard.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, well I have another issue now.

Comment: ok , no I have the problem that the main domain ( example.com ) don't resolve to anything, only the subdomains do, I want the main domain to be resolved through the internet ( e.g through 8.8.8.8).

Comment: If you have a wildcard of `*.example.com` it does not match by design `example.com` so if you need records there you need to enter them specifically alongside the ones for the wildcard.

Comment: thank you for the reply
I have searched a lot for the issue I have. what I need is ALIAS record type which is not supported by BIND. :(

Comment: It won't be supported by any browser, since it is not a standard record but only something proprietary that some DNS provider do, each one differently. The future will be SVCB/HTTPS records which standard is not yet fully done but they are already available at at least one DNS provider and consumed by browsers soon.